# Parametrizing dynamic sql query (VB.Net)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have an unsecured query which allows for an injection, and I'm not sure how to go about parameterizing it to prevent said injection

```
Dim sInsertSQL As String
sInsertSQL = "Insert into tbl_userprop (Prop_Def) values "

        Dim tempString As String() = PropertyDefinitions.Split("|")
        For i As Integer = 1 To tempString.Length

            If tempString(i - 1).Length > 0 Then
                sInsertSQL = sInsertSQL + " ('" + tempString(i - 1) + "'),"
                bInsert = True
            End If

        Next
```

There are up to 10 values stored in tempString and they are concatenated onto sInsertSQL as such: ('val1'), ('val2'), etc

Figured it out, update for the curious:

```
        Dim lstParams As New Collections.Generic.List(Of SqlParameter)
        Dim tempString As String() = PropertyDefinitions.Split("|")
        For i As Integer = 1 To tempString.Length

            If tempString(i - 1).Length > 0 Then
                Dim sParamName As String = String.Format("@param{0}", i)
                Dim sparam As New SqlParameter(sParamName, tempString(i - 1))
                lstParams.Add(sparam)
                sInsertSQL = sInsertSQL + " (" + sParamName + "),"
                bInsert = True
            End If

        Next
```

Comment: Consider just performing individual parameterized inserts wrapped in a transaction. The difference in network roundtrips and performance should be minimal, while the code will become much simpler. Passing a table-valued parameter is another option.

Comment: you could also consider .net BulkInsert command

Comment: Another vote for a TVP or using SqlBulkCopy

Comment: I've got a code sample for SQLBulkCopy in .net if you need it, what I did is made an empty datatable representing the table (can be got in code by querying SELECT....WHERE 1 = 0  then the datatable is populated, and fired into the SQLBulkCopy

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, everyone, I've figured out how to do it in a relatively simple way. Update above for those curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have split the string you know how many parameters there will be, so you can create the @ items for the SQL. After that, you can add the parameters by going through the lists of parameter names and values:

```
Dim PropertyDefinitions = "abc|def|ghi|jkl|mno"
Dim values = PropertyDefinitions.Split({"|"c})

Dim paramNames = Enumerable.Range(0, values.Count()).Select(Function(n) $"@p{n}")
Dim paramList = String.Join(", ", paramNames.Select(Function(s) $"({s})"))

Dim sql = "INSERT INTO [tbl_userprop] (Prop_Def) VALUES " & paramList
' The following line with the sample data would output '
' INSERT INTO [tbl_userprop] (Prop_Def) VALUES (@p0), (@p1), (@p2), (@p3), (@p4)
'Console.WriteLine(sql)


Dim connStr = "YourConnectionStringHere"

Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
        For i = 0 To values.Count() - 1
            'TODO: Set the .SqlDbType and .Size to conform to the database definition of [tbl_userprop]. '
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = paramNames(i),
                                                      .Value = values(i),
                                                      .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                                                      .Size = 99})
        Next

        'conn.Open()
        'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End Using

End Using
```